# How to embed content inside an Angular directive ($compile?)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create an multi-select directive for Angular, similar to a 'select' but where multiple options can be chosen.

The basic structure works, but I want/need to be able to specify an optional template used for the display of the strings. For example, a user can choose from a list of options, but the text displayed is passed through a translate filter.

I cannot work out how to get the template to work, I've messed about with `compile` rather than `link`, but didn't get anywhere, and I suspect using `$compile` may help, but I'm new to Angular and having some trouble there too.

[Here is the current progress in Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Qh4cxJH1dl6248mA6qfj)

I want to change the `{{item}}` lines in the template to contain the string specified in the `display-template` attribute e.g. `{{item | simpleFilter}}` but it does not get evaluated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Simon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `displayTemplate: '='` on your view, because you are going to evaluate this value in directive template, I'd suggest you to don't pass it in isolated scope. Do write your expression which needs to be evaluated inside attribute & create template using `attrs.displayTemplate`

**Markup**

```
<multi-select ng-model="output" source="input" display-template="item | simpleFilter">
    </multi-select>
```

**Directive**

```
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template:function(element, attrs){
      return '    <div dropdown class="form-control" tabindex="0"' +
        '     style="position:relative; padding: 0; min-height:66px; max-height:66px;">' +
        '    <div class="input-group-addon pull-right btn btn-default" type="button" dropdown-toggle style="width:33px; height:100%; border-top-width: 0; border-bottom-width: 0; border-top-left-radius: 0; border-bottom-left-radius: 0;">' +
        '         <span class="caret"></span>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <div style="min-height:66px; max-height:66px; overflow-y: auto;">' +
        '        <div style="display: inline-block; padding: 2px; margin: 2px; border-width:1px; border-style:solid;"' +
        '              data-ng-repeat="item in ngModel">' +
        '              <span>{{item}}</span>' +
        '             <button type="button" class="close"' +
        '                 ng-click="removeItem(item)"' +
        '                 style="padding-left: 2px; padding-right: 2px;">' +
        '                 &times;' +
        '            </button>' +
        '        </div>' +
        '    </div>' +
        '    <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="top:initial; left:initial; width:100%; position:absolute; margin: 0;">' +
        '        <li ng-repeat="item in source">' +
        '            <a  ng-click="addItem(item)">{{'+ attrs.displayTemplate +'}}</a>' +
        '        </li>' +
        '    </ul>' +
        '    </div>'},


    scope: {
        source: '=',
        ngModel: '='
    },
    require: 'ngModel',
    replace: true,
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.addItem = function(item) {
            if (scope.ngModel === undefined) {
                scope.ngModel = [];
            }

            if (scope.ngModel.indexOf(item) === -1) {
                scope.ngModel.push(item);
            }
        };

        scope.removeItem = function(item) {
            var index = scope.ngModel.indexOf(item);
            scope.ngModel.splice(index, 1);
            if (scope.ngModel.length === 0) {
                scope.ngModel = undefined;
            }
        };
    }

};
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/zPG74EuFx9dpaFDC6bYD?p=preview)

Comment: That is perfect. Exactly what I was after. Thank you!